# Can't animate rotation simultaneously with other properties, only in Safari (not Chrome)

Tags: jquery, animation, safari

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Safari: Absolutely positioned DIVs not moving when updated via DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9471038/safari-absolutely-positioned-divs-not-moving-when-updated-via-dom)

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5463375/291022) to another question explains a small hack that lets you use jQuery to animate an element's rotation.

In my situation, I wanted to animate an element's rotation simultaneously with its top: and left: properties. So I came up with [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s5Bqa/4/).

```
function transformThing() {
    $('#thing').animate({ top: '+=50', left: '+=50', borderSpacing: -90 }, {
        step: function(now,fx) {
            if(fx.prop === 'borderSpacing') {
                $(this).css('-webkit-transform','rotate('+now+'deg)');
                $(this).css('-moz-transform','rotate('+now+'deg)'); 
                $(this).css('transform','rotate('+now+'deg)'); 
            }
        },
        duration: 1000
    }, 'swing');
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#thing').click(function () {
        transformThing();
    });
});
```

Clicking the square *should* rotate it and move it down and to the right. And this is what it does, *except* in Safari. I'm running Safari 5.1.5 on Mac OS X 10.7.3, and only the rotation animates.

A coworker found [this jQuery plugin](http://www.zachstronaut.com/posts/2009/08/07/jquery-animate-css-rotate-scale.html) that lets you do the same thing with cleaner syntax, but it exhibits the same problem.

If you look in the Web Inspector, you can see the top: and left: values changing, and in fact they change to the correct values; but they don't affect the visual layout of the element unless you turn them off and on again.

Clearly, the answer is "Um, duh, it's a Safari bug." But is there any deeper explanation that might help me find a workaround, or anything else I can try?

Comment: I had a similar problem and found my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9471038/safari-absolutely-positioned-divs-not-moving-when-updated-via-dom In short, set the rotate style in a setTimeout() by itself. Alternatively, it is suggested that using translate for the top/left properties instead of setting top/left directly may also fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the short answer is it wont work in safari. but the good news is it works fine if you use canvas like this example : http://beta.rallyinteractive.com/ the work animations rotate / transform / animate a sprite. Its really the only type of answer i can see anyone giving you.