# CSS transforms not loading correctly in Safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari, transform

I've just encountered a very weird issue. Basically, Safari seems to be applying transforms to elements *after* the page has been fully loaded (or sometimes once the window has been resized), which results in an ugly flash of unstyled content. I've already tried adding `backface-visibility` in hope that it will fix the issue, but to no avail.

Here's the issue on CodePen: http://codepen.io/goodpixels/full/NPVdGy/

It works perfectly fine in Chrome and Firefox, yet in Safari it doesn't work until the window is redrawn. Any thoughts on how this can be fixed? I'm on a Mac.

Comment: Your codepen seems to be not visible.

Comment: It's visible, it's list light grey on white background.

Comment: which safari version? And have you checked this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9471038/safari-absolutely-positioned-divs-not-moving-when-updated-via-dom